# Writing big files to blob store and running out of memory

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using the experimental blobstore file API to write a CSV file containing some event data. There's a lot of data so I'm batching up the writes. My code is running in a backend so I have lots of time but I'm running out of memory, and I don't understand why.

Here's the code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from google.appengine.api import files

q = Event.all()

events = q.fetch(50)
while events:
    with files.open(blobname, 'a') as f:
        buf = StringIO()

        for event in events:
            buf.write(event.id)
            buf.write(',')
            buf.write(`event.logged`)
            buf.write(',')
            buf.write(event.type)
            buf.write(',')
            buf.write(event.timestamp)
            buf.write(',')

            needAmpersand = False
            for prop in event.dynamic_properties():
                if needAmpersand:
                    buf.write('&')
                needAmpersand = True
                buf.write(prop + '=' + str(getattr(event, prop)))
            buf.write('\n')

        f.write(buf.getvalue())
        buf.close()

    events = q.fetch(50)

files.finalize(blobname)
```

This code makes it round the while events loop about 20 times before the process aborts having used up more than 140 mb of memory. Event is a database model specific to this application. An Event is basically the record of something happening on a remote machine, later these Events will be processed by a map reduce operation to build stats, for now I just want to download them. There are 100's of 1000s of events in our database (later we'll also switch to storing them differently but for now this is it).

I note that the with `f.open` causes `f.close` to be called each time it finishes the with clause, as `f.close()` is called by `f.__exit__()`

An earlier instantiation of this code just called f.write(..) on each element that is being written to 'StringIO'. This earlier version ran out of memory much more quickly but otherwise behaved similarly. There is still something about this code that causes it to leak memory.

Help?

**Update**
I've just tried commenting out the f.write(buf.getvalue()) and though it obviously doesn't create a blobstore item with anything in it, it does eventually complete having processed all the Event entities. Am I missing something or does f.write() leak memory or buffer up everything until finalize()?

Comment: what is `Event`? An AppEngine object?

Comment: What did "the original version" do? It's not helpful to know it 'barfed sooner' without knowing what it did.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question to provide clearer info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `f.write(buf.getvalue())` you are asking the `StringIO` to turn itself into a single memory object and passing that. That's going to be expensive.

Try `buf.seek(0)`, which will rewind back to the start of the stream, and just passing `f.write(buf)`. `StringIO` is a file-like object, and `f.write` should be able to read through it as a stream.

Look at the [source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/files/file_service_pb.py), it's not clear from the docs or code whether a `file_service_pb.AppendRequest` can deal with StringIO. Try it.

Comment: Useful observation, I'll play with it. However `buf.getvalue()` may have to make a temporary copy of the string, which I agree is inefficient, but it shouldn't leak. It makes it round the loop 20+ times before it runs out of memory. If I switched, it might make it round an extra time because the peak memory is lower but it shouldn't fix the overall problem.

Comment: Indeed. Your "`file`" may also be storing up its own buffer. Not in a position to check at the moment, but try looking for a `flush` method on the GAE file object.